# Page layout issue

Tags: horizontal-alignment, titles

I am writing my thesis and using latex for first time. I would like to modify the the first page of my thesis, as it shows only name of thesis, my name etc. I would like to move all  text little-bit to right-side, just on the first page, without effecting the other pages of thesis. Any idea how can I do it?

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 
    12pt, 
    twoside, 
    openright, 
    cleardoublepage=empty, 
    numbers=noenddot, 
    appendixprefix, 
    BCOR1.5cm, 
    bibliography=totoc 
    ]{scrbook} 

\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}

%xyz

\end{center}
\end{titlepage}
\clearpage
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please add a MWE to your post. BTW: Your tag `biblatex` is very irritating.

Comment: There are so many possibilities understanding your needs. Please specify your result.

Answer (score 1):

Although you did not provide a MWE (which should be compilable and demonstrate your problem) I guess you just want some marginal space at the left of your titlepage.

Since you are using KOMA you may use a `addmargin` environment as follows:

```
\begin{addmargin}[<left indent>]{<right indent>}
    % your titlepage
\end{addmargin}
```

This results in:
[image: desired indent]

And this is the code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside,openright,cleardoublepage=empty, 
    numbers=noenddot,appendixprefix,BCOR=1.5cm,% <- important eqaul sign 
bibliography=totoc 
    ]{scrbook} 

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{addmargin}[5cm]{0pt}
\begin{center}
\lipsum[1]
\end{center}
\end{addmargin}
\end{titlepage}
\clearpage
\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```