# Title Page layout issue

Tags: horizontal-alignment, titles

I am writing my thesis and using latex for first time. I would like to modify the the first page of my thesis, as it shows only name of thesis, my name etc. I would like to move all text little-bit to right-side, just on the first page, without effecting the other pages of thesis. Any idea how can I do it? I use ''right'' alignment instead of center, but it did not work.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 
    12pt, 
    twoside, 
    openright, 
    cleardoublepage=empty, 
    numbers=noenddot, 
    appendixprefix, 
    BCOR1.5cm, 
    bibliography=totoc 

    ]{scrbook} 



\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}


%xyz


\end{center}
\end{titlepage}
\clearpage
```

Comment: This is most likely the same question as http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/353207/page-layout-issue, most likely the user has two accounts

Comment: It looks like you've got two separate accounts, which means you cannot edit your original post or leave comments. The Stack Exchange staff can [merge them together for you](http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can change the page dimensions with `\usepackage{geometry}`. So you can set a bigger margin on the left side(one page).

`\geometry{...}`: define global borders:

`\newgeometry{...}` : change borders

`\restoregeometry` : back to default/global values

Example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, 
    twoside, openright, 
    cleardoublepage=empty, 
    numbers=noenddot, appendixprefix, 
    BCOR1.5cm, bibliography=totoc 
    ]{scrbook} 
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{   %<-------------------------------------global values
  left=3cm,
  right=3cm,
  top=2cm,
  bottom=4cm,
  bindingoffset=5mm
}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{titlepage}
\newgeometry{ %<----------------------------------new values(titlepage)
  left=12cm,
  right=6cm,
  top=4cm,
  bottom=8cm,
  bindingoffset=5mm
}
\begin{center}
    \LARGE{\textsc{TITEL}}\\    
\end{center}
\end{titlepage}
\restoregeometry % back to default <---------------restore global values
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Comment: Large is a switch, not a macro that takes an argument.